# Searching all jpg's from all drives in a computer vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search

I want to list all JPG files from all drives in a computer with there full path.
So I tried following code but it only list few random files, it wont search all files. i got this from here: [Searching a drive with vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022677/searching-a-drive-with-vb-net)

```
Public Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String)
    Dim fl As String

    Try
        For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            For Each fl In Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg")
                listbox1.Items.Add(fl)

            Next

            DirSearch(dir)
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

'form1 load event

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DirSearch("c:\")
    DirSearch("d:\")
    DirSearch("e:\")
    DirSearch("f:\")
    DirSearch("g:\")
    DirSearch("h:\")
    DirSearch("i:\")
    DirSearch("j:\")
    DirSearch("k:\")
    'DirSearch("so on.....")
    savetxtfile()

   End Sub
```

Save searched result to text file in system drive

```
Sub savetxtfile()
    Dim systemdrv As String = Mid(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 1, 3)


    TextBox1.Text = listbox1.Items.Count
    Dim w As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim r As IO.StreamReader

    Dim i As Integer
    w = New IO.StreamWriter(systemdrv + "temp\test.txt")
    For i = 0 To listbox1.Items.Count - 1
        w.WriteLine(listbox1.Items.Item(i))
    Next
    w.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ignoring your exception...

```
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
```

Use this instead (so you can't miss it for debugging)...

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

---

Knowing that what's happening is probably a folder access error, you need to handle that accordingly.

```
For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
    Try
        For Each fl In Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg")
            lstbxTest.Items.Add(fl)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Continue For
    End Try
Next
```

Effectively, continue if you get an error, because you don't really care in this case.

You might want to add some exceptions in there (If dir = "whatever" Then Continue For) so you're not trying to go through every single system folder in operating system.

Comment: It is inside a `For Loop`. You need to check your code. I changed mine (yours) so that it would catch errors but ignore them and `Continue For`.